# Acces Violation en C y otros problemas

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria, codeblocks, memoria

En la aplicación que estoy desarrollando tiene que haber una serie de librerías, pues bien, en determinadas funciones que manipulan estructuras de datos me salta un error -1073741819 0xC0000005 (lo he buscado y ponía que correspondía con el tema de Acces Violation). Adjunto un ejemplo de una de las funciones que presentan esta problemática:

```
void borraFiltro(FILTROS* filtros, int posicion){
    int i;

    if(filtros == NULL || filtros->p == NULL){//Falla porque cuando no hay filtros establecidos detecta que si los hay
        printf("ERROR: no existen filtros establecidos.\n\n");
    }else{
        if(filtros->num < posicion){//Falla
            printf("ERROR: %d excede al numero total de filtros(%d).\n\n", posicion, filtros->num);
        }else if(posicion < 1){
          printf("ERROR: %d debe ser un numero entre 1 y el numero total de filtros(%d).\n\n", posicion, filtros->num);
        }else{

            FILTRO* puntero1 = filtros->p;

            if(puntero1->next == NULL){
                eliminaFiltro(puntero1);
                filtros->p = NULL;
            }else{
                FILTRO* puntero2 = puntero1->next;
                for(i=1;i<posicion && puntero1 != NULL;i++){//Verificacion fin de lista
                    puntero2 = puntero1; //Salva el puntero anterior
                    puntero1 = puntero1->next;
                }
                if(puntero1 == NULL){//validación extra por si la lista está cortada
                    eliminaFiltro(puntero2);
                }else{
                    puntero2->next = puntero1->next;//AQUI SALTA EL FALLO
                    if(filtros->p == puntero1){ //Veficar si el elemento a eliminar es el primero
                        filtros->p = puntero1->next;
                    }
                    eliminaFiltro(puntero1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Definicion de la estructura de datos llamada filtro:

```
typedef struct fil {
    COLUMNA * pCol;         //puntero a la columna
    OPERANDO operador;      //operación a realizar
    char *valor;            //valor a aplicar
    struct fil *next;   //puntero al siguiente filtro
} FILTRO;
```

Funcion encargada de generar una ED filtro:

```
FILTRO* generaFiltro(COLUMNA* columna, char c_operador[], char valor[]){
    FILTRO* filtro = (FILTRO*) malloc(sizeof (FILTRO));

    filtro->valor = (char*)malloc((strlen(valor)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(filtro->valor, valor);

    filtro->pCol = (COLUMNA*) malloc(sizeof (COLUMNA));
    filtro->pCol = columna;

    if(strcmp(c_operador,"==") == 0){
       filtro->operador = IGUAL;
    }else if(strcmp(c_operador,"!=") == 0){
       filtro->operador = DISTINTO;
    }else if(strcmp(c_operador,">") == 0){
        filtro->operador = MENOR;
    }else if(strcmp(c_operador,">=") == 0){
        filtro->operador = MENORIGUAL;
    }else if(strcmp(c_operador,"<") == 0){
        filtro->operador = MAYOR;
    }else if(strcmp(c_operador,"<=") == 0){
        filtro->operador = MAYORIGUAL;
    }

    filtro->next = (FILTRO*) malloc(sizeof (FILTRO));
    filtro->next = NULL;

    return filtro;
}
```

Definicion de la ED filtros:

```
typedef struct {
    int num;    //numero de filtros contenidos en la lista
    FILTRO *p;  //puntero al primer filtro
}FILTROS;
```

Funcion encargada de generar el ED filtros:

```
FILTROS* generaFiltros(){
    FILTROS* filtros = (FILTROS*) calloc(1,sizeof (FILTROS));
    filtros->p = (FILTRO*) calloc(1,sizeof (FILTRO));
    filtros->p = NULL;
    return filtros;
}
```

En cuanto a los problemas menores, son los comentados en la primera pieza de código: falla la evaluación de filtros->num < posicion. Además, pese a las correcciones realizadas en base a algunas de las respuestas. La verificacion de si existen o no filtros falla.

Comment: Qué sentido tiene que hagas un `malloc` y luego le asignes la dirección de memoria de otra estructura? Cuando hagas el correspondiente `free`, tendrás un problema. Cosas como esta: `filtro->pCol = (COLUMNA*) malloc(sizeof (COLUMNA));` y a continuación:  `filtro->pCol = columna;`. De estas tienes varias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

revisa lo siguiente:

- en la inicialización de `FILTROS`, **p** se inicialize con NULL
- verifica el valor de la variable `filtros`

```c
  if(filtros == NULL || filtros->p == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: no existen filtros establecidos.\n\n");
  }
```

- Revisa el código que recorre los `FILTROS`, parece incorrecto pues faltan validaciones, prueba con este:

```c
FILTRO* puntero1 = filtros->p;

if(puntero1->next == NULL){//revisar
    eliminaFiltro(puntero1);
    filtros->p = NULL; //Borrar la referencia de p
}else{
{
    FILTRO* puntero2 = puntero1;
    for(i=1; i<posicion && puntero1 != NULL; i++){ //Verificas el fin de la lista
        puntero2 = puntero1; //Salva el puntero anterior
        puntero1 = puntero1->next; //Te mueves al siguiente
    }
    if(puntero1 == NULL){//validación extra por si la lista está cortada
        eliminaFiltro(puntero2);
    }else{
        puntero2->next = puntero1->next;
        if(filtros->p == puntero1){ //Veficar si el elemento a eliminar es el primero
            filtros->p = puntero1->next;
        }
        eliminaFiltro(puntero1);
    }
}
```

Comment: he implementado el los cambios que has sugerido al código y he revisado que en la inicialización de filtros, p se inicie en NULL(esto ya ocurría) pero sigue saltando el mismo problema

Comment: @carlos  revisa la linea 19, tienes un error ahí: donde pones `FILTRO* puntero2 = puntero1->next;` debería ser `FILTRO* puntero2 = puntero1;`

Answer (score 1):

Suena a que el último elemento de tu lista no tiene el *next* a NULL.

Ten en cuenta que al pedir memoria (el malloc) el valor de *next* no tiene porqué estar a NULL automáticamente.

También es posible (aunque menos probable) de que inicialices el *next* a NULL y luego en alguna operación de memoria haya un buffer overflow y escribas donde no toca, afectando al valor de *next*.

Por último, noto que haces

```
           if(puntero2->next == NULL){
                eliminaFiltro(puntero2);
            }else{
```

con lo cual supongo que liberas *puntero2*, pero no veo que asignes NULL a *puntero1->next*. Así que *puntero1->next* apuntaría a una posición no NULL que sin embargo ya ha sido liberada. No creo que esto te cause el problema que describes (si fuera eso el error te saldría en el *free*) pero es un ejemplo de lo delicada que es la gestión dinámica de memoria.

En todo caso tendrás que ir depurando todo tu código poco a poco, la gestión de memoria en C/C++ se presta a muchos fallos a no ser que seas muy organizado.

Comment: Tal y como se muestra en el código que proporciono, siempre que genero un nuevo filtro el next lo pongo a null con: filtro->next = NULL;

Comment: @carlos si en vez de `malloc` usas `calloc` te ahorras las dos inicializaciones a 0 y null que haces para cada filtro

Comment: @eferion Como podrás ver, he editado el código proporcionado. Ahora utilizo el calloc en lugar del malloc pero sige saltando el fallo

Comment: @carlos no he dicho que te fuese a solucionar el problema, era solo una posible mejora de esa parte del código

Comment: @eferion `calloc` inicializa todo a `0`, incluyendo si es un puntero. Pero `NULL` no siempre es `0`, eso depende de la implementación. Preferible inicializar a `NULL` manualmente..

Comment: @MrDave1999 eso que dices hace referencia a arquitecturas antiguas o a cuando la macro no estaba incluida en el estándar. Hoy en día esas _chapuzas_ no se dan o al menos no tengo constancia de ellas.